# AWS Elastic Beanstalk 100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, instance, health-check

See Health check, I did everything as per the requirements but It seems like some health problem. Can someone help here?
100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx.
ELB processes are not healthy on all instances.
ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.
Impaired services on all instances.
[See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvgGt.png)

Comment: What are your HC settings? Do they agree with what you app is returing? HC path, HTTP code?

Comment: Yes, I have fixed top 3 errors but, I'm still facing an error like "Impaired services on all instances". Can you please check this?